# Delete a path too long

Tags: root-access, delete

An unstable version of Android 5.1.1 caused a bootloop on my phone. I fixed things, but after the incident the `0` directory located inside `/storage/emulated/0` dived **DEEPLY DOWN**. Now I can't delete anything inside.

I guess it's because the path is too long. I successfully used 7zip once I had that problem in Windows, I wonder if something like [robocopy](https://superuser.com/a/467814) or [subst](https://superuser.com/a/755301) method is possible on Android. Here's a screenshot of me gaining root access and then trying to wipe things out which was not successfull.

[image: Screenshot_Image_1]

<sub>Screenshot - (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Comment: Wow, that looks crazy! storage/emulated/0 isn't "real"
and you shouldn't be deleting 0,
if you are trying to clean out /data/media/0 pass a wildcard
rm -fr /data/media/0/*
that will flush out your internal "sdcard"

Comment: @moonbutt74 Man, I am so grateful to you for clarifying things about paths. I though that if any FM with root-access opens `/storage/emulated/0` when you choose "internal memory", it's what I need. Everything worked out **awesome** because I was able to delete only the mentioned directory w/o "formatting" internal memory

Comment: @moonbutt74 looks like your comment helped OP! Consider reposting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that looks crazy! `/storage/emulated/0` isn't "real" and you shouldn't be deleting 0, if you are trying to clean out `/data/media/0` pass a wildcard `rm -fr /data/media/0/*` that will flush out your internal "sdcard"